# Can phosphoric acid be used to substitute sulfuric acid in the synthesis of thymolphthalein?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am planning to synthesize thymolphthalein, a pH indicator. I am wondering if phosphoric acid can be used to substitute sulfuric acid in the preparation. I know it can catalyze Friedel-Crafts reactions, which are a part of the synthesis. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: Thymolphthalein synthesis]

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could attach an image of the normal synthesis involving sulphuric acid. Would help those who are not aware of the compound. Thank you :)

Comment: If you use polyphosphoric acid (PPA) I think it will work. PTSA will also probably work

Comment: What is your reasoning *for*, what is your reasoning *against* the substitution of the strong Bronsted acid $\ce{H2SO4}$ by phosphoric acid (i.e., review of the literature)?  By the way, the waxy [polyphosphoric acid](https://www.emdmillipore.com/US/en/product/Polyphosphoric-acid,MDA_CHEM-807471) may be considered, too ([an elder review](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr50020a004), [a current application](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.orglett.1c02057)).

Comment: I do chemistry in a workspace with wooden benches, and sulfuric acid would eat through them quickly. Thanks for suggesting those, I can make or get both of those.

Comment: But the question is: would straight phsophoric acid work?

Comment: @Jacob Are you asking about tthe commercially avialable 85% phosphoric acid solution or the 99% crystalline material? The 99% material might do it, I doubt the 85% solution would.

Comment: The phenol will be more reactive than a normal benzene, by being a phenol + the alkyl groups in addition; this with using an acid anhydride may suggest less need (quantity / strength) of catalyst / less harsh reaction conditions here.  However, consider the  concurrent esterification (phenol-OH + carboxylic acid), too.

Comment: The reaction is a friedel crafts reaction, and it forms water. The reaction to form the thymolphthalein is irreversible, but esterification is. Also, phenols are sterically bulky, so this is not favored.

Comment: Thanks, all! Polyphosphoric acid does indeed work to catalyze this reaction. I was successful in making it.

Comment: @Jacob If you find your answer, kindly self-answer it. It completes your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used polyphosphoric acid and it worked.